# Sending Email with content from PHP/Mysql

Tags: php, email, newsletter

I want to send emails where the data is from a php/mySQL query.

I know that html will render in the email but i don't think the php codes will.

So is there any way where i can send emails with content queried from a mySQL DB ?

I already search here, there is one topic that covers it but the person who advised suggested a pdf export or to use a 3rd party tool which in my case are not applicable.

Thank you for the help guys :)

Comment: The php script is executed on your server, there's no need to have a client execute your php script. You fetch strings from the database, put them in some kind of template and send the resulting string.

Comment: I suspect you'll get more help if you provide more information.  It sounds like you're already sending emails (how else would you know the "html will render"?), so what command/technique are you using to do it?  That will determine how you might render other data.  php has pipe and proc_open for running commands and reading their output - once you've read the SQL results into a string, you might - for instance - need to encode for HTML rendering - e.g. &gt; for < etc..  Both a pipe and encoding are general mechanisms for such tasks, but you want want to render into an HTML table...?

Comment: when i send for example <a href="www.google.com"> google </a> , i know it will "render" but if i send <?php ?> blocks of code as email, they won't "render", right ? 

Tony: can you please please provide a tiny sample of code ? 

Sorry for the noobishness :$

Comment: `but if i send <?php ?> blocks of code as email,` - Why would you want to do that? Yes, they wouldn't be executed unless the recipient did install a client side php (actionscript) handler - which is veeery unlikely.

Comment: thanks for following up volkerk - if for example i want to send the user their profile for example - i query the data using <?php ?> from mysql - then to send it to them as email, i should ?????

( really sorry for noobish question again )

Comment: `i query the data using <?php ?> from mysql` ...and then you have fetched some strings from your database. Now put those strings in your mail-template. Can be as simple as `$msg = "Hello $row[username], ...";` can be as complex as http://swiftmailer.org/docs/decorator-plugin-replacements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.net) to generate the email on the server. It makes it very easy to generate multi-part messages (plaintext + html, with attachments and embedded/inline images). Basically:

```
// set up PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SetFrom('you@yourserver.com');
$mail->AddReplyTo('you@somewhereelse.com');
$mail->Subject('Your profile');
$mail->IsHTML(TRUE);

// do your database query
$con = connect_to_database();
$stmt = run_database_query($con, "SELECT ... FROM ...");

$data = fetch_from_database($stmt);


// set the email address
$mail->AddAddress($data['email'], $data['fullname']);


// html content for smart email clients
$html = <<<EOL
<h1>Welcome</h1>

<p>Your username is {$data['username']}.</p>
EOL;

// plain text alternate content
$text = <<<EOL
Welcome

Your username is {$data['username']}.
EOL;

// add the content to the mail
$mail->MsgHTML($html);
// add alternate content 
$mail->AltBody($text);


// send the mail
if ($mail->Send()) {
   // mail sent correctly
} else {
   die("Uhoh, could not send to {$mail['email']}:" . $mail->ErrorInfo);
}
```

Comment: trying this out <3 thanks :D but i am getting error on EOL - i tried removing, replacing with quotes...:$

Comment: Oops. `$text = <<<EOF;` <--shouldn't have had a semicolon there. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid spam issues you can wrap the `PHPMailer` in a class and instantiate that at every e-mail address read from the database table.

For each email address you can create a new instance and do kind of a `->setMailAddr($mail,$fullName)` and after send the e-mail destroy this instance.

The ideal is to place a new instance at every POST. In this case, you can put a FORM into the page.